# local dependencies from root multi project build in gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been working on an android app built using the ResearchStack skin framework pulled in through the gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'org.researchstack:skin:1.1.2'.
```

I am interested in possibly doing some customization to the underlying ResearchStack skin framework:

```
https://github.com/ResearchStack/ResearchStack.
```

Can anyone walk me through updating my project to be dependent on local ResearchStack build artifacts so that I can make changes to the framework and see those changes in my local application.

I tried just pointing to the build output:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: '../../ResearchStack/skin/build/outputs/aar', include: ['*.aar'])
```

but that leaves me with unresolved transitive dependencies and some build issues that I couldn't quite get worked out.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
John,
Put 'ResearchStack skin framework code' in another directory 'myResearchStack' at root level parallel to 'app' directory.
And update the root level 'build.gradle' as

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android { ... }

dependencies {
    // Dependency on a local library module
    implementation project(":myResearchStack")


}
```

Comment: Thanks, that more or less put me on the right path. I copied the ResearchStack/skin directory into my project, added ':skin' to the include in settings.gradle, and     implementation project(':skin') in the app/build.gradle dependencies. Then tweak the skin and app build.gradle files to remove incompatibilities and add dependencies until any build errors went away. I did not change the root level build.gradle.